# Python - удалить элемент из списка, если справа стоит аналогичный элемент

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

`In [1]: example = [1, 2, 'a', 3, 3, 'v', 'x', 'm', 'm', 1]` - у нас есть такой пайтон список.
Нужно удалить элементы такие, если есть справа по соседству аналогичный элемент.
Т.е. сначала проверим, какие элементы вообще не одни.

```
In [3]: [i for i in example if example.count(i) > 1]                                          
Out[3]: [1, 3, 3, 'm', 'm', 1]
```

С нашего списка нужно удалить `3` и `m`, так как справа стоят такие же данные - тройка и m.
Вот как это сделать, чтобы в итоге наш список экземпл превратился в
`[1, 2, 'a', 3, 'v', 'x', 'm', 1]`   ???

P.S. последовательность элементов нужно сохранить.

Comment: Нужно вернуть список уникальных ключей, или всё же удалить элемент если справа от него стоит такой же?

Comment: последовательность нужно сохранить. обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


example = [1, 2, 'a', 3, 3, 'v', 'x', 'm', 'm', 1]
result = [j for i, j in pairwise([None] + example) if i != j]
```

Comment: Подключить библиотеку и вызвать несколько функций для такой простой задачи - не слишком сурово ? :) Питон - страшная сила

Comment: @splash58 itertools - часть стандартной библиотеки, не требуется никаких "подключений", кроме импорта.

Comment: Это я так - старческая брюзга :)

Answer (score 3):

Наверное, можно проще

```
b = [example[x] for x in range(len(example)) if [example[x]] != example[x+1:x+2]]

# [1, 2, 'a', 3, 'v', 'x', 'm', 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так.

```
example = [1, 2, 'a', 3, 3, 'v', 'x', 'm', 'm', 1]
lst = [] # Храним индексы для удаления
for i in range(len(example)-1):
    if example[i] == example[i+1]:
        lst.append(i)
for i in lst: # Удаляем по сохраненным индексам
    example.pop(i)
print(example)
```